How to specify someip method-id and event-id in ARXML (classic autosar)
Are there dedicated tags to specify someip deployment information inside ARXML of classic autosar?
(For Franca IDL it can be specified in fdepl file: SomeIpMethodID)

Additionally to the definiton of the SOMEIP Protocol and SOMEIP-SD ServiceDiscovery specs, the AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate ch. 6.5.7 (Ethernet specific description) should be considered. (Provided/Consumed-ServiceInstances, EventHandlers/EventGroups, ... ).
